# minimizing the number of if clauses

Tags: c++, algorithm

help with ranking scores
Hello I want to ask you all for an efficient algorithm regarding ranking scores.

We take three things into account. The amount of balls in the goal, the amount of balls that the haven't been shot by the players yet/each player has five balls) and the player number( player 1 , player 2)

If two players play the game then the score distribution should look like this:

for example the player that has more balls in the goal is the winner and then I have a char array winner[2] . in the index 0 the player that is the winner is stored and in index 1 the player that didn't win get's stored.

If it should turn out that they both have the same amount of balls in the goal then the amount of balls that haven't been shot yet should determine the winner.

If this is also the same then the lowest player number should decide the winner.( which is either 1 or 2)

Here an example if player 2 has more balls in goals than players 2

```
number_of_goals_player_1 = 3;
number_of_goals_player_2 = 4;

number_of_balls_player_1 = 3;
number_of_balls_player_2 = 3

winners[0] = player_2;
winners[1] = player_1;
```

The other cases which I described aren't that hard just some if comparisons.

However if I want to do it for 3 players or 4 players I would have a lot of if clauses.

This is where I need help. There should be a way more efficient way to do this.

For three players for example I would have a winner array with size 3 and then at index one the first ranked player and index two second ranked player and index 3 player with the lowest score.

I hope this is understandable.
If not then I would be happy to edit my question
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a data structure:

```
struct player {
    int goals = 0;
    int balls = 0;
};
```

Then use a vector:

```
std::vector<player> players;
```

Then use `std::sort` to sort it:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(players.begin(),players.end(),[](const player& a,const player& b) {
         return .... put logic to decide if a is better than b here ....
});
```

The player that compares better than all others will be the first entry in the vector:

```
if (players.size() > 0) auto best_player = players[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! and this will also work if there are more than 2 players?

Comment: and which values should I sort? Don't quite understand what is getting sorted

Comment: @konoha you sort them according to their score. You can think of the predicate as `a < b` and `a < b` is `true` when `a` has a better score than `b`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think you should also add an ```id``` to the struct, in case we need to use the player number as a tie breaker

Comment: Oh thanks I get it! One last question if I have 3 players for example how can I add the second best players to players[1]?

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur true gonna add that too

Comment: @konoha after sorting the vector the second best is `players[1]`

Comment: could you give me an example of the logic to decide if a is better than b ? do you mean something like this `if a.goals > b.goals` ? a contains the biggest number and b the smallest number I believe.

Comment: @konoha it could be eg `return a.goals > b.goals` yes. The exact condition I didnt understand from your question. Its not easy to avoid many if clauses when there is not a single if clause in your code ;)

Comment: oh ok. the only thing i have a problem understanding is if for example I have three players. and let's say player 1 and 2 and 3 have the same amount of goals but player 1 has the most balls and player 3 has the second most amount of balls. How should I make the code determine the order? `return a.balls > c.balls > b.balls` ?

Comment: @konoha you don't need to compare three players. You create a vector of `N` players and sort it, for that you only need to specifiy how you want to compare 2 players